# ngFor and ngModel resseting input when pushing into array

Tags: angular, binding, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to create a form where you can add multiple lines before sending it. For that I'm using storing data in an array of Lines and use ngFor and ngModel to bind / retrieve data into my form.

Here is what my code looks like

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  lines : Line[] = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.lines.push(new Line("XXXXXX1",0,0));
  }

  addLine(){
    let line = (new Line("XXXXXX1",0,0));
    this.lines.push(line);
  }

  save(){
    console.log(this.lines);
  }
}

class Line {
  type: string;
  qteRejet : number;
  qteComm : number;

  constructor(type: string = "XXXX1", qteRej: number = 0, qteComm : number = 0){
    this.type = type;
    this.qteRejet = qteRej;
    this.qteComm = qteComm;
  }
}
```

and the form :

```
      <div class="form-group">
          <div class="row" *ngFor="let line of lines; let ind=index;">
            <div class="col-lg-1">
              <i class="fa fa-2x fa-plus-square add-btn" (click)="addLine()" *ngIf="lines[lines.length-1] === line"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3">
              <select class="form-control" name="type" [(ngModel)]="lines[ind].type">
                <option>XXXXXX1</option>
                <option>XXXXXX2</option>
                <option>XXXXXX3</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <input class="form-control" type="number" min="0" name="qteCommande" [(ngModel)]="lines[ind].qteComm">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
              <input class="form-control" type="number" min="0" name="qteRejet" [(ngModel)]="lines[ind].qteRejet">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

When I add all the lines at once, the form works perfectly. Now when I try to **fill a line then add another line**, for some reason, the form resets the lines previously entered.

[image]

But when I check my array, it still has the entered values

[image]

Can someone explain what is going on here / what I am doing wrong ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT : I tried, as suggested by **@Ploppy** to use trackBy and added an id to my lines. I also added this line to the form :

```
<p>{{line.id}} | {{line.type}} | {{line.qteComm}} | {{line.qteRejet}}</p>
```

And this is what's happening :
[image]

The form resets but the values are correctly binded.

Comment: As a bonus, you can change your constructor to only this and remove the variable declaration above the constructor: constructor(public type: string = "XXXX1", public qteRej: number = 0, public qteComm : number = 0) { }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I finally figured out the problem in my code. My inputs were inside a `form`, and adding a new line added an input with the same `name`(Which is not allowed in Agular 2). Replacing my `name` attributes by `name=attribute-{{id}}`solved the problem.

```
<div class="form-group">
      <div class="row" *ngFor="let line of lines; let ind=index;">
        <div class="col-lg-1">
          <i class="fa fa-2x fa-plus-square add-btn" (click)="addLine()" *ngIf="lines[lines.length-1] === line"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3">
          <select class="form-control" name="type-{{ind}}" [(ngModel)]="lines[ind].type">
            <option>XXXXXX1</option>
            <option>XXXXXX2</option>
            <option>XXXXXX3</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <input class="form-control" type="number" min="0" name="qteCommande-{{ind}}" [(ngModel)]="lines[ind].qteComm">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <input class="form-control" type="number" min="0" name="qteRejet-{{ind}}" [(ngModel)]="lines[ind].qteRejet">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is a Plunker that summaries everything : **[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OC2RQQBX9WLIQdZfrAGX?p=preview)**

Comment: self answered? .

Comment: Yes, I figured it out after sometime.

Comment: Why the downvote ? This did solve the problem, am I doing it wrong or something?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Angular recreates the DOM because it does not recognize the lines. In order to help him, you need to use the trackBy method of the *ngFor directive and identify the items by a unique property.

```
*ngFor="let line of lines; let ind=index; trackBy:trackByFn"
```

In your component:

```
trackByFn(index,item){
  return item.myCustomIndex; // myCustomIndex should be unique
}
```

By default the trackBy method return the index of the item from its array.

Comment: I just tried by adding an id to my lines and using trackBy but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: I fixed a typo, in the method declaration. You can check if it works by doing a console.log(item.myCustomIndex) in the method.

Comment: Check my edit, its seems to recognize the lines correctly but still resets the form for some reason