# how to generate dynamic user input without clearing fields (see GIF)

Tags: angular, dynamic, ionic2

I'm having an issue when creating dynamic user input fields. Whenever I generate a new field all of the content within the field disappears. I'll provide a screenshot to illustrate the problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgUCu.jpg

Relevant code:

HTML:

```
  <ion-item *ngFor="let field of fields">
    <ion-label fixed>Destination </ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="field.name" name="name"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <button  ion-button color="light" icon-right (click)="addDestination()" >
      Add Destination
      <ion-icon name="add" ></ion-icon>
  </button>
```

Typescript:

```
export class HomePage {
  fields: any;
  public destination1;
  public destination2;
  public destinations = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.fields = [];
  }

  addDestination(){
    this.fields.push({name: ''});
  }
}
```

Any ideas/solutions?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this.fields.push({name: ''}) updating any field with name attribute to an empty string?

Comment: Ahhh yes that is it. Any suggestions on a workaround?

Comment: @Adrianopolis No, he is pushing a new object, it should not affect the existing objects

Comment: @Dansmith12 each input field name should be unique. Once you submit your final form you will have to decide how to handle the data. Was your intention to lump all those guys together in a list? maybe index the name attirbutes?

Comment: I've got everything working now. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the [exact same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42761763/ngfor-and-ngmodel-resseting-input-when-pushing-into-array) 3 days ago, you cannot have different `input`s with the same `name` attribute inside a `form` it will keep binding the value to the last input. This should solve your problem :

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let field of fields;let id = index">
    <ion-label fixed>Destination </ion-label>
    <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="field.name" name="name-{{id}}"></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <button  ion-button color="light" icon-right (click)="addDestination()" >
      Add Destination
      <ion-icon name="add" ></ion-icon>
  </button>
```

Comment: @YounesM LOL This is exactly what I told him in my comment? The issue was the name attribute not being unique. Why did you suggest I was not correct?

Comment: @Adrianopolis you suggested that the `name` field was replaced by `name=''` because of the pushed object, which is not. All the fields will have `name = "name"` inside them because of the loop and Angular doesn't allow that. If it is not what you meant, I might have misunderstood what your were saying.